# fired from frontend job - what to improve

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

Yesterday my employee let me out saying that quality of my work was not enough. I am (was?) a Frontend Developer. It was quite of shock, but I'm planning to improve myself to prevent that situations in the future. In the company I was passing from one project to another until amount of projects ended. Most of projects I made to the end, but clients were in main cases not satisfied. Now, maybe I don't have 10 years of experience, but I know some tools and libraries. I know what preprocessors are, what is webpack/gulp are for, what is the use of jQuery and NodeJS. I know some ES2015. I have some knowledge, but when I'm working long in one difficult task/one project having no clue where the problem lies, the task is beating me off and I get irritated very quickly and my work entusiasm goes to 0. I think that's my problem. Also, I am afraid of starting of project, I have some kind of phobia, because everytime on the beginning of the project there are so many information, so many new people (and sometime a lot of technologies) that I can't stand it. And that learingn process is very hard and painful at the beginning. I think I have a lot of disadvantages - like laziness for example. If I don't know how to do the task and googling doesn't help, I'm pannicing and I don't know what to do and try to find some silly things on the internet to make me calm. Sometimes it helps, but I'm losting a lot of time i think. And the work day lasts only 8 hours (usually i don't work afterhours). I have some disadvantages, but I'm trying to motivate myself and I want to learn now at home some other technologies like CoffeeScript (for now, that was rather reading about it than coding).

But overall - I think the main problems here are: 1) lacks in knowledge (i had to remind with google what are differences between rem and em in CSS) and 2) speed of my work. I know that for first there is only one way to improve it (sacrifice some time for learing/reading/coding/studying/taking courses), but for second? What are the technics which helps me to develop my code faster? I don't know Yeoman well, but if it helps me a lot in starting the projects? Are there some good technics which helps me in working faster in WebStorm? And finally - is there is something I'm missing? Are there some more things which I need to improve?

There might be one anwser - that whole programming thing is not for me, but I don't like to think in that way, because I can't do anything else. :)

Are there companies which want to hire people like me? And is it good place for such posts? :o

Comment: If you are having panic attacks due to "so many technologies..." etc. maybe you went into the wrong field?  You list your skillset but almost any developer has some sense of it so your frontend work doesn't show much experience.

Comment: Vote to close, very broad and we can't tell you what you need to do, we don't know you well enough

Comment: "the task is beating me off" - consider rephrashing this.

Comment: You need to get rid of the idea that you need to be motivated to work. From what you wrote I see persistence as your biggest problem. You don't keep at things until you succeed. You get frustrated and go off and google cat videos. Work isn't fun and you need to learn to do it anyway.  You need to fail and pick yourself up and fail again and again until you succeed. There is never an excuse for saying you didn't do your work because you lost your motivation.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me you have several issues, but maybe some advice from an "old salt" will help:

1) Don't get scared to ask for help. Speaking from a place very similar to yours, I used to be very shy about asking an older dev if I had a question, fearing they would see me as uneducated or unworthy. As an older developer now, I find that it gives me a thrill to explain things I know to an up-and-coming newbie, mainly because they could tell ME something I didn't know. Ask for help when you don't know something. You're already doing that here, so why not in the workplace when they have more of a direct knowledge of what you're doing.

2) Laziness and "distracting" yourself is a bad idea. You have to keep at it. Yes, a break now and then when your brain is fried after that one piece of code hasn't worked all day is refreshing, but looking at cat pictures only slows you down. Make sure to take lunch, get away from the computer and take the time to zone a bit. I tend to eat and wool-gather at lunch (at my desk) which allows my brain time to relax and flex to a situation I might be stuck on. In addition, at this point in your career, you can learn tech at home, looking up things about jquery and the like, but DO NOT take work home. Leave the specifics behind, or it'll make you unwilling to work on it during work hours (burnout).

3) Starting a project can be daunting. If you don't know where to start, work with your supervisor or manager to outline the requirements very clearly, and then pick a piece to work on first. This allows you to set up "blocks" of things to work on (database, front end, etc) and then get your head around it, and this in turn allows you some flex on WHAT to work on so that you don't get stuck/bored. Today I will work on Database, tomorrow interface, etc.

Lastly, get yourself past bad behavior. Lists of things to do, organization, diligence, all good practice that will get you into good habits. A list of things to do gives you a sense of accomplishment when you get to cross something off, and allows you the visual representation of what to do and when.

Also, stop saying you can't do anything else. That's a lie to yourself you HAVE to stop. Maybe programming isn't your thing...it takes a certain type of person and mindset, and you might not have it. That doesn't mean you can't do anything else. Perhaps Held Desk is more your speed, with more moving about and interaction. Perhaps you can work on networking, or maybe something outside of the IT field altogether. That's more of what interests you enough to be passionate about it. Reading your post it doesn't seem like programming is interesting enough to you that it can become a career, and you don't want to go 10 years trying to do something you dislike before having to jump ship and change paths. Think hard about what you love to do, and then put in time and effort into being good at it, and that will make you (and your employer) MUCH happier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Being let go can be traumatic, but it's not the end of the world. Usually it indicates that you are not a good fit in that particular position at this point in time, and does not necessarily reflect your overall abilities.

You can hopefully take some solace in the fact that what you are experiencing is common -- there's [analysis paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis), which often strikes at the beginning of projects, and the proliferation of technology options which is seemingly more complicated every day. There is absolutely nothing wrong with Googling pieces of technical info -- no one knows every little thing about every little thing.

**But remember that technology is merely a tool to solve problems people have.** Your solution or stack does not need to be the latest and greatest in order to solve those problems. Make sure you are focused on what the customer needs -- you may be too caught up in the technical weeds and not looking at what will solve the fundamental issues quickly and efficiently.

Two ways to avoid being overwhelmed:

1. Be concerned about only on those things you can control
2. Dedicate your attention to only one thing at a time

The best way to improve is to simply work and create solutions, whether they are side projects or for a client or employer. Along the way you will find efficiencies in the way you work, and which tools are right for you. **There is never one ideal, perfect way to solve a particular problem.**